# Function is returning none and I don't know why

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code and for whatever reason, it returns `none` after it executes. Does anyone know why?

```
def function():
    try:
        ctr = 0
        total = 0
        file = open("text.txt", 'r')
        while ctr <= 15:
            ctr += 1
            for line in file:
                line = line.strip("\n")
                num = float(line)
                total += num
        average = total / 15
        return average
    except ValueError:
        total = total
```

Comment: You need to indent the whole function body, starting with the `try:` line.

Comment: Indentation is critical in Python, you have to be very careful when you're copying code.

Comment: To answer your question, None is the default return value for Python.  The minimal code that exhibits this behavior is `def f(): pass`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you want to read your file and compute the average of the numbers it contains, ignoring any lines that contain non-numbers. Your current code doesn't do this correctly because your `try` and `except` are at too high a level. You also have two loops where you probably only need one.

Try moving the exception handling inside of a single loop over the file contents:

```
def function():
    ctr = 0
    total = 0

    with open("text.txt", 'r') as file:   # a with statement will close the file for you
        for line in file:   # just one loop
            try:
                num = float(line)   # this may raise an exception!
                ctr += 1
                total += num
            except ValueError:   # ignore ValueError exceptions in the loop
                pass

    if ctr > 0:
        average = total / ctr
    else:
        average = 0   # or maybe raise an exception here, for a file with no numbers?

    return average
```

If you need to limit the average to 15 values, you can probably add an extra check for `ctr` being greater than 15 in the loop. I left that part out because it wasn't clear from your non-working code what you wanted to do exactly (count lines or count numbers?).

Answer (score 1):

After the Value Error, you are not returning anything.

```
   except ValueError:
        total = total 
        return ???
```

Are you sure the float(line) is not the source of an error that is causing a possible ValueError?

Comment: That should only matter if there's an error in the `try` block.

Comment: Ya, but if there is, then his program would return None as he says, right?

Comment: What if I want to continue to run through the program even after the exception is raised?

Comment: You aren't raising any exception, so you can continue.

Comment: Initialize your `average` variable before the loop (it defaults to `None`). Also, consider using `finally`.

Comment: @AdamHughes An exception will be raised when this executes

Answer (score 0):

Too much to put in the comments, but what is the output of this code?

```
def function():
    average = 0

    try:
        ctr = 0
        total = 0
        file = open("text.txt", 'r')
        while ctr <= 15:
            ctr += 1
            for line in file:
                line = line.strip("\n")
                num = float(line)
                total += num
        average = total / 15
        return average
    except ValueError as e:
        total = total #What?
        print("Caught ValueError")
        return e
    except Exception as e:
        print("Caught Exception")
        return e
    print("At the end...")
    return False

ve = function()
```

Comment: Did you update the print statements to python3? (I missed that initially)

Comment: What does that mean? Sorry, I'm pretty new to python.

Comment: It means the print syntax has changed from v2 to v3, thus most likely causing your SyntaxError, though I can't be sure. See the updated code. Also, it's helpful to post the details of error messages, and attempt to fix SyntaxErrors to be sure it's not a problem copying/pasting. Your problem, as Adam stated, is due to you not returning anything at the end of your function. I'm trying to determine what your function is actually doing. My guess is, catching an error and returning None, because there's nothing to return.

Comment: It printed "Caught ValueError." The program is trying to take text from a text file, verify that the text on the line is a number, adds all the numbers up and finds the average. There are non-numeric entries in the file, so I'm trying to get around those.

Comment: I updated the code to add `ve = function()`. Run `python -i script.py`, which will run it in interactive mode. From there, you can access the exception with the var `ve`. Alternatively, pull your code out of the try/catch block, and let it crash instead of catching the ValueError. Look at the backtrace and specific error message, and fix your code accordingly.